# Filling NAN data with mode() doesn't work -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nan

I have a data set in which there is a series known as `Outlet_Size` which contain either of `{'Medium', nan, 'High', 'Small'}` around 2566 records are missing so I thought to fill it with mode() value so I wrote something like this :

```
  train['Outlet_Size']=train['Outlet_Size'].fillna(train['Outlet_Size'].dropna().mode()]
```

But when I tried to find number of missing NaN record by command

```
  sum(train['Outlet_Size'].isnull())
```

it is still showing 2566 NaN records.Why is it so ?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that `mode` returns a series and this is causing the `fillna` to fail, if we look at a simple example:

```
In [194]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['low','low',np.NaN,'medium','medium','medium','medium']})
df

Out[194]:
        a
0     low
1     low
2     NaN
3  medium
4  medium
5  medium
6  medium

In [195]:    
df['a'].fillna(df['a'].mode())

Out[195]:
0       low
1       low
2       NaN
3    medium
4    medium
5    medium
6    medium
Name: a, dtype: object
```

So you can see that it fails above, if we look at what `mode` returns:

```
In [196]:    
df['a'].mode()

Out[196]:
0    medium
dtype: object
```

it's a series albeit with a single row, so when you pass this to `fillna` it only fills the first row, so what you want is to get the scalar value by indexing into the `Series`:

```
In [197]:    
df['a'].fillna(df['a'].mode()[0])

Out[197]:
0       low
1       low
2    medium
3    medium
4    medium
5    medium
6    medium
Name: a, dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

Regarding whether `dropna` is required, no it isn't:

```
In [204]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['low','low',np.NaN,'medium','medium','medium','medium',np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
df['a'].mode()

Out[204]:
0    medium
dtype: object
```

You can see that `NaN` is ignored